# Nested routes pointing to wrong routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

In my routes file

```
  resources :shops do
    resources :products
  end
```

I have a product listing such as

```
        <% @products.each do |p| %>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="text-center"><%= link_to p.name, shop_product_path(p) %></p>
            <p class="text-center"><strike>Rs.250</strike>&nbsp;<strong>Rs.<%= p.price %></strong></p>
            <center><%= link_to "Order now", new_product_order_path(p), :class => "btn btn-primary" %></center>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

But this link here

```
<p class="text-center"><%= link_to p.name, shop_product_path(p) %></p>
```

It points to

```
http://localhost:5000/shops/6/products/1
```

But this should be like

```
http://localhost:5000/shops/1/products/6
```

what is the mistake here?

Comment: what is `p.id` and `p.shop_id`?

Comment: product id is 6 and shop id is 1

Comment: I think you need to pass both ids to the route helper

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass both objects

```
<p class="text-center"><%= link_to p.name, shop_product_path(@shop, p) %></p>
```

p is @product in the loop.